# How can I factor this bivariate polynomial over the reals?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I know it can't be factored over the rationals. But I believe it may be factored over the reals into two or four bivaritate polynomials with real coefficients. (from looking at the graph). Or prove it is not possible. (This is one equation written over two lines)

$144y^8-360x^2y^6-2400y^6+297x^4y^4-2160x^2y^4+7504
 y^4-90x^6y^2+2070x^4y^2-16040x^2y^2-6080y^2+9x^8-
 426x^6+8113x^4-74048x^2+270400$

(Is there a good way to factor polynomials over the reals? Is there some free software to do it?)

Comment: Try it with Wolfram (or maple etc...). Or are you just asking for *existence* of such a factorization over the reals, even if one can only approximate the coefficients?

Comment: At first I'm just trying to find out if it can be factorised and have approximate real coefficients.

Comment: the homogeneous degree 8 part factors, it is zero when $x=\pm y$ and when $x=\pm 2y.$ Along those directions, degree six dominates, and is largely negative. Suggest switching to polar coordinates. Where did you get this?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear this is one equation written over two lines to fit it in. This equation came out of some calculations based on elliptical contour lines.